# Item Updating And Item Updated Event-Reciever Field values gets null for InfoPath Form Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow, infopath, event-receiver

I have a InfoPath form library and custom visual studio workflow associated with it. And also I have a Event-Receiver for the library. When I Update the list item as Following code part the item Updating event of the Event-Receiver is firing.

```
memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDocument.OuterXml));
web.Lists[WorkflowProperties.ListId].GetItemById(WorkflowProperties.ItemId).File.SaveBinary(memoryStream);
```

But the **After properties** and **Before Properties** all the **fields shown as null**.
`properties.BeforeProperties["Name"]`

Why **Item Updated event** and **Item Updating field** values gets null for this form library?

I am using InfoPath 2007 and Visual studio 2008 with SharePoint 2007.